# Laravel if field is empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm new to laravel

I have a host-profile.blade.php that has

```
<input type='text' name='cc_cvv' value='{{ $creditcard->card_cvv }}'>
```

and i got UserController.php

```
public function host(){

$this->params['creditcard'] = Creditcard::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->first();

return View::make('users.host-profile', $this->params);

}
```

the thing is, it throws an error if my table 'creditcards' is empty/truncated because it cant find any user_id in it. How will i be able to show empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blade has a nice [`or` shortcut](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#other-blade-control-structures) for this use case.

```
{{ $creditcard->card_cvv or '' }}
```

This is the same as:

```
{{ isset($creditcard->card_cvv) ? $creditcard->card_cvv : '' }}
```